# How to convert yyyymm to Mon-yyyy?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, format, sql-server-2012

I have a column YearMonth with the value like (201208). I would like to convert the entire column to Aug-2012 (Mon-Year) format. I did upto this point.

```
select Convert(varchar(11),Cast(right(yearmonth,2)+'-'+left(yearmonth,4) as varchar (11)),0)
from report.TEST
```

This code changed 201208 to 08-2012 but then I couldn't change it to Aug-2012. Any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: This will higly depend on what RDBMS you are using. So, please tell us wich one is it (and the version).

Comment: Hi Lamak, I have been using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) 
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Actually, for SQL Server 2012, there is the [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(DATE,yearmonth+'01'), N'MMM-yyyy', 'en-US') AS YearMonth;
```

Comment: +1 For the "better newer way". I just wish MS didn't wait so bloody long to add it :-/

Answer (score 1):

For MS-SQL

```
DECLARE @d1 INT; SET @d1 = 201208
DECLARE @d2 VARCHAR(6); SET @d2 = 201208


SELECT 'data type'='int'
, 'in'=@d1
, 'out'=CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), CAST(LEFT(@d1,6)+'01' AS DATE), 107) 
  + '-' + LEFT(@d1,4)

SELECT 'data type'='varchar'
, 'in'=@d2
, 'out'=CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), CAST(@d2+'01' AS DATE), 107) 
  + '-' +LEFT(@d2,4)


/* -- OUTPUT
data type   in      out
int         201208  Aug-2012

data type   in      out
varchar     201208  Aug-2012
*/
```

You can also make use of the DATENAME

```
SELECT 'data type' = 'int'
, 'in' = @d1
, 'out' = LEFT(DATENAME(month, CAST(LEFT(@d1,6)+'01' AS DATE)), 3) 
  + '-' + LEFT(@d1,4)

SELECT 'data type' = 'varchar'
, 'in' = @d2
, 'out' = LEFT(DATENAME(month, CAST(@d2+'01' AS DATE)), 3)
  + '-' + LEFT(@d2,4)
```

Or use different STUFF :)

```
DECLARE @d1 INT; SET @d1 = 201208
DECLARE @d2 VARCHAR(6); SET @d2 = 201208


SELECT 'data type' = 'int'
, 'in' = @d1
, 'out' = STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CAST(LEFT(@d1,6)+'01' AS DATE), 107), 4, 5, '-')

SELECT 'data type' = 'varchar'
, 'in' = @d2
, 'out' = STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CAST(@d2+'01' AS DATE), 107), 4, 5, '-')
```

Comment: Thank you Leoinfo for the suggestion. I appreciate it.

Comment: A dumb question. If you dont mind, could you please explain '01'. Sorry, I am learning it too. Thanks

Comment: Well, when you CAST to DATE the 201208 you get "Dec 08, 2020". So, if you add "01" you CAST 20120801 to "Aug 01, 2012"

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to turn 08-2012 into a valid datetime, but this does the trick.

```
SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 106), 8), ' ', '-') AS [Mon-YYYY]
```

Source: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: Thanks Anthony for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

`select Substring(Convert(VarChar(11),Convert(DateTime,SomeMinthYear) + '01',113),4,8)` would be one way.
e.g. convert the date to one of the formatted strings with a mon yyyy in the format and then chop it out.